# PHP adding key-value pairs to array where value is an array and key is ID

Tags: php, dictionary

I am trying to format my data for easy display after a database query. I have tried different suggestions from other questions but no luck.
Data looks something like this (result joined from three tables):

```
BOOK_ID  |  FIRST_NAME  | LAST_NAME    
------------------------------
1        |  Jack        | Smith
1        |  Jill        | Smith
3        |  Mary        | Poppins
```

The example data BOOK_ID is an ID of a book, second and third column together is the book author's name. A book can have multiple authors.

My desired result would be:

```
Array (    
     [1] => Array ( "Jack Smith", "Jill Smith" ),
     [3] => Array ( "Mary Poppins" )
)
```

The ID of the book is the key and the value is an array of all the authors.
However I have not found a way to create such an array.
Pseudocode for achieving this:

```
$stmt = < SQL statement here >;
$stmt->execute();
$data = [];    
    
foreach ($stmt as $row) {    
    if (< key exists in data >) {
         // add name to the value array of the key    
    } else {    
         // insert new key with the first name
    }    
}
```

I tried to do this:

```
$data[] = array($row['bookId'] => array($row['firstName'] . " " . $row['lastName']));
```

But this resulted in this:

```
Array (    
     [0] => Array ( 
           [1] => Array (
                  [0] => "Jack Smith"
           )
     )
)
```

How can I achieve my goal?

Comment: `$data[$row['bookId']][] = $row['firstName'] . " " . $row['lastName']`?

Comment: Can you USE PDOs `FETCH_UNIQUE` or an equivalent alongside a group_concat in the mysql query?  https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/fetch_modes#FETCH_UNIQUE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this?

```
$books = [];

foreach ($stmt as $row) {
    $books[$row['BOOK_ID']][] = $row['FIRST_NAME'].' '. $row['LAST_NAME'];
}
```